# How do I get a working directory of Spark executor in Java?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I need to know a current working directory URI/URL of Spark executor so I can copy some dependencies there before job executes. How do I get in Java ? What api should I call?

Comment: Spark executors are not long-lived processes, and you can't control where they run in the cluster

Comment: @cricket_007 If YARN knows where to put archives for spark-submit so it could be done in code as well in the main jar

Comment: Right, that's what `SparkFiles` is for, as answered. But your definition of "in code" probably means the driver process, not the executors

Answer (score 1):

Working directory is application specific so you want be able to get it before  applications starts. It is best to use standard Spark mechanisms:

- `--jars` / `spark.jars` - for JAR files.
- `pyFiles` - for Python dependencies.
- `SparkFiles` /  `--files` / `--archives` - for everything else

Comment: --archives does not always work. At least not on Azure Hdinsight I am using, so I have to resort to programmatic way until Microsoft fixes it or documents properly...